# Why can't HTTP URLs be resolved on my local network?

Tags: networking, router, dns, http

If I visit, for instance, http://tutor.com in any browser on my computer, I get a network timeout.  But if I visit https://tutor.com it loads. This problem occurs with all devices on the network (Windows, Android, iOS, MacOS), for both wired and wireless connections, and is not specific to that site.

I don't see how the protocol prefix would even matter for DNS resolution, and nslookup works just fine.  But then why does the HTTP request time out?  The normal behavior would be:

1. tutor.com resolves to IP address
2. http request returns a 301 redirect to https
3. https request succeeds

Here is what happens using PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://tutor.com/
Invoke-WebRequest: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..

Invoke-WebRequest https://tutor.com/

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

I know this works on other networks (my daughter took her computer to a relative's house and it works fine there -- redirecting and loading https://tutor.com).

In a browser, I can work around the problem by prefixing with https instead, but the problem is that the tutor.com application is requesting http URLs, which don't work on my network.  What could be causing this behavior, and how can I troubleshoot?

My O/S is Windows 10 20H2 19042.985.  I have an ASUS RT-AC66U primary router and a tp-link AX6000 configured as an access point.  I am using these OpenDNS IPs https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/#familyshield for DNS servers (I also tried configuring the router to connect to DNS server automatically but it made no difference).

Comment: Does the relative's house use the same ISP as you? Does it work if you use a VPN?

Comment: The relative does have the same ISP.  I am going to try a VPN next.

Comment: Network timeouts in browsers are often not DNS related. DNS timeout is traditionally 2 seconds. how long does it take to timeout when you try it? if its 2 Minutes, then that is an HTTP timeout, not a DNS related issue.

Comment: Yes, it is port 80 that must be blocked.  Not DNS.

Comment: And it does work through a VPN.

Comment: Have you checked the [URL filter of your router](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1037946/) ?

Comment: I'd also try to [factory reset the router](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1000925/). Since you seem to have this issue since 2 years now, you might also want to consider to borrow a router from someone for some days, or to get a (secondhand) replacement, to be sure it's not the router.

Comment: Have you installed the latest [ASUS RT-AC66U B1 Firmware version](https://www.asus.com/us/networking-iot-servers/wifi-routers/asus-wifi-routers/rt-ac66u-b1/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=RT-AC66U-B1)? If this doesn't help, try to reset the router to stock settings and re-enter your identification for the ISP.

Comment: Firewall - URL Filter is disabled.  I get "The router's current firmware is the latest version." when checking for firmware updates in the router.  I also tried with another router that I have and same issue.

Comment: Which router have you replaced ? Primary or access point ?

Comment: Some notes from your example (http://tutor.com): _firefox-like_ browsers often automatically change `http` to `https`, by default. From a basic browser like `lynx` I am able to read error `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`  when trying to load http page that is forwarded to the port 433. Then reload via https. Check firewall**s** rules on the port 433 (**s** means on your system and more probably on the router); do not forget to check on which ports  your _application_ works .

Comment: If you have the same issue with a different router and with different PCs, then the issue is with your ISP. It could be a misconfiguration of their firewall. Maybe you can do a last test by setting up a hotspot with your mobile phone, and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: It does, and I have used that at times to get around the problem but it's a hassle.  I can also use a VPN but also less than ideal.  I'm pretty sure it's not the ISP, since a relative that lives nearby uses the same ISP and doesn't have the issue.

Comment: Interesting; Does it happen on websites like Google? If "Yes" - Then it is 100% something to do with your router ( since it's not some kind of software ). Is there any Firewall rules enabled regarding port 80? Can you run Test-NetConnection from powershell toward a service like 1.1.1.1 and see if there's a connection on port 80?

Comment: @harrymc asked which router was replaced/tried, based on a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1653190/why-cant-http-urls-be-resolved-on-my-local-network#comment2781284_1781176) it seems OP replaced the access point which wouldn't help LAN/wired devices connect to main asus router. Agree on factory resetting asus. Alternatively [check asus router firewall & network services](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013636/) tab which can explicitly block http/80

Comment: There is no access point.  Just a DSL modem and ASUS router.  I have examined the settings of both multiple times and can find nothing that would block port 80.

Comment: Output of Test-NetConnection 1.1.1.1:
`ComputerName           : 1.1.1.1
RemoteAddress          : 1.1.1.1
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 192.168.1.212
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 7 ms`

Comment: Output of `Invoke-WebRequest http://google.com/
Invoke-WebRequest: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..`

Comment: I'd like to avoid re-configuring the router unless truly necessary.  Is there still a compelling reason to think that could make a difference based on the info I have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When did this problem start? Do you know what was changed when issue started?
2. Process of elimination can help troubleshoot many things. You are trying a variation of that by making a change, testing, confirming that change did not fix, rinse repeat. I'd like you to try a more basic version: disconnect everything you can to bare bone essentials then add equipment/changes one by one. This is literal guidance from PC manufacturers to find culprit hardware. In your situation I'd disconnect every router you can & plug directly into your internet providers equipment to see if you can access many HTTP pages. If you can you know the problem isn't there so add a router or configuration one by one, test, rinse repeat.
3. Based on you OpenDNS & linking to Family Shield I have to assume you are trying to do website-blocking/content-filtering. While trying to block bad stuff on the internet I suspect you made another change that indirectly caused this issue. Since you nor us can seem to figure out the exact setting it's probably good to start from the ground up slowly & methodically
4. You mention you replaced a router, but didn't specify which one (as you noted you use two)? [@harrymc asked this in comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1653190/why-cant-http-urls-be-resolved-on-my-local-network#comment2779947_1653190)
5. [1NN in question comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1653190/why-cant-http-urls-be-resolved-on-my-local-network#comment2779411_1653190) asked you to factory reset router which I think is a good idea, but you never seemed to respond to that.
6. You CAN dive deeper into the rabbit hole, which in my eyes just prolongs your issue because it only gets more complex. However hey you're learning :)

   a) install nmap popular port scanner. Try to port scan 80 (HTTP) on a website, TBH I am not sure this will help you understand your network as its goal is just to see if the port is open on the remote server which it should be if it's hosting a website

   b) Get Wireshark installed & capture network traffic. It's very verbose as you are literally seeing the network packets/frames happening so lots of white noise & you need to understand how networking works very intimately

Comment: 1. A couple of years ago. No.

Comment: 4. TP-Link AX6000
will try some of the other suggestions

Comment: So based on that router model & your original question that appears to be the Wi-Fi Access Point router. That wouldn't help you if the issue is happening on LAN/wired connecting to main router (Asus). Googling the error you get on PS cmdlet `invoke-webrequest` everyone usually indicates its a firewall issue or a web server misconfiguration, the later being unlikely since its many websites. If I were in your situation & you insist on not removing all routers except the ISP's your best bet is capturing wireshark info. Could also do a tracert to see what hops/routers to a domain

Comment: Will you factory reset main asus router? If not can you explain why. Alternatively [check asus router firewall & network services](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013636/) tab which can explicitly block http/80

Comment: [ASUS RT-AC66U manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/RT-AC66U_B1/E11885_RT-AC66U-B1_Manual.pdf?model=RT-AC66U-B1) indicates Advanced Settings has a System Log which might shed some light. pg75 speaks about the network services filter. pg73 indicates you can turn off the firewall which I would briefly do to see if its the culprit. pg32 General, Parental Control. Pg28 QoS could briefly disable as pg30 mentions it can drop lower priority packets. Manual doesn't talk about it, but router product page mentions 'AiProtection Powered by Trend Micro' & app control; maybe something there?

Comment: https://www.asus.com/content/aiprotection/
https://www.asus.com/us/networking-iot-servers/wifi-routers/asus-wifi-routers/rt-ac66u-b1/
Also kind request to upvote any answers or comments that you deem helpful even if they don't necessarily solve your issue, they are helping you, & narrowing it down

Comment: `tracert captive.apple.com

Tracing route to captive.g.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  modem.Home [192.168.0.1]
  3     6 ms     5 ms     5 ms  hlrn-dsl-gw05.hlrn.qwest.net [207.225.112.5]
  4     5 ms     6 ms    11 ms  63-225-124-33.hlrn.qwest.net [63.225.124.33]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6    12 ms     6 ms     6 ms  4.14.113.110
  7     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  usden5-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]`

Comment: I have tried disabling the firewall in the router & modem.  Network Services filter is disabled. DoS protection disabled.  Router mode is wireless router, not access point. Parental controls disabled. Traffic manager disabled. DNS server is 208.67.222.123

Comment: I'd like to avoid re-configuring the router unless truly necessary.  Is there still a compelling reason to think that could make a difference based on the info I have provided?

Comment: Tracert indicates two NAT's: AKA your Asus router is doing translation & your ISP (quest) modem. This is not usually a problem, but could be. If you plug PC directly into ISP/qwest modem can you reproduce your issue?

Comment: 208.67.222.123 is OpenDNS Family Shield. Please temporarily change it to another DNS sever that doesn't do parentel/website blocking like googles 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1

Comment: I changed the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and it didn't help.  Here is what I get when connecting directly to the DSL modem:
`invoke-webrequest http://captive.apple.com
invoke-webrequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.`

Comment: `tracert captive.apple.com

Tracing route to captive.g.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  modem.Home [192.168.0.1]
  2     5 ms     5 ms     4 ms  hlrn-dsl-gw05.hlrn.qwest.net [207.225.112.5]
  3     4 ms     4 ms     5 ms  63-225-124-33.hlrn.qwest.net [63.225.124.33]
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    10 ms    29 ms    16 ms  4.14.113.110
  6     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  usden5-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145709/discussion-between-gregg-and-kyle-a).

Comment: The issue was resolved by factory resetting the DSL modem.

Answer (score 3):

While dns can cause timeouts, this timeout has nothing to do with DNS.

The issue is that http and https are on different ports, and apparently the http port is firewalled from you.  If nothing was listening on the remote port, you would get a connection refused instead.

Possibilities here include but are not limited to:

- Your local host is firewalling http for some reason
- Your upstream router is firewalling http
- Something upstream from your router (your isp?) is firewalling http
- The remote host has firewalled http and may or may not be listening on that port.  (But if you can connect to it from other locations, this isn't the case.)
- The upstream host is running DoS prevention software (like fail2ban) and you have managed to trigger it
- The host is currently undergoing a DoS attack and is unable to respond in a timely way
- The remote host is down (but then https would also not work)
- The remote host is actually a pool of hosts (in the cloud) and the one randomly assigned to service your http request is temporarily down; subsequent attempts might work (or just further trigger the DoS prevention listed above)

Comment: How would I diagnose that?  I disabled the firewall in the ASUS router (which I have a wired connection to), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It may not be the router firewalling the connection.  It could be the local host or something upstream from the router.  It could also be the target host firealling it, but if it works from other locations, this is unlikely unless you've triggered a DoS throttle on the remote host.

Comment: I checked my router and DSL modem, and neither are configured to block port 80.  I tried disabling the firewall in both and it didn't help.  It has to be something with my network, but I am stumped.

Comment: It's not the remote host.  It never works, and other sites have the same issue.  And when I am connected to my work VPN, it also works.

Comment: It may be a firewall on your local host.  Malware might also interfere with DNS, and https might be using DNS over https and bypassing that.

Comment: I also checked the firewall on my computer.  And again, the problem is not specific to my computer.

Comment: It could be a misconfiguration in the DNS on your router, partially covered up by dns over https.   To diagnose this, use something like nslookup or dig to try to resolve the external hostname into an ip address.  If this works, it's not dns.   And a DoS mitigation method could still block your entire local network.

Comment: I already tried nslookup and it works.

Comment: If nslookup works, then it has to be a firewall somewhere, you just haven't found it yet.  Someting like TCPtraceroute might help narrow it down.

Comment: Just saw the "work vpn" comment.  This could also bypass a local firewall.  Does nslookup give you the same ip address with and without the work VPN?

Comment: My IP address is different under the VPN.  Maybe with a VPN active, the local network has no idea about the request itself since everything is encrypted, and it can't filter port 80?

Comment: Two separate issues here.  If the request goes through the VPN tunnel,  if there is a local firewall, it will be bypassed.  It's not the encryption but the tunnel that does this.  However, if nslokup returns a different IP for your target host with and without the vpn, then you probably have a malicous DNS server set in your router.

Comment: nslookup always returns the same IP for the target host.  But my IP address changes when on the VPN.  I still can't find the firewall that is blocking port 80.

Comment: The only effect your changing ip address might have is to fool remote DoS tools like fail2ban.  Hae you looked for and tried a tcptraceroute?

Comment: Yes, I tried tracetcp tutor.com:80, and get Destination Reached -- Trace Complete (I can't include the full output in a comment).

Comment: If tcptraceroute and wget works, then it might be a problem with the browser itself.  Look for proxy settings in the browser or try a different browser maybe.

Comment: I get the same results with Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, on Windows, Android, MacOS, and iOS devices.  The browsers are not configured with custom proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at three possibilities.  Your router or DSL modem...

1. is blocking inbound HTTP traffic
2. is blocking unsecure 301 redirects (http)
3. has an outbound rule blocking or misrouting your HTTP request

You can rule out Options 1 & 3, by attempting to visit a purely http site (no redirect), such as http://captive.apple.com/  <-- You should get a plain white page that says, "Success".  If this page fails to load, you would need to find the offending rule/setting on your modem or router.

You can test #2 by visiting, http://neverssl.com. This is another http-only page, but it includes a 301 redirect to "[random_server_name].neverssl.com/online/".  Same solution as above, if this fails.

Finally to narrow down whether the router or DSL modem(or ISP) is the cause, you should be able connect the DSL modem directly to a computer and try the same tests.

If you're able to narrow down the failure to the DSL modem, but can't find the offending setting/rule, call your ISP and confirm they don't have any kind of filtering or proprietary "security enhancements" enabled on your connection and ask for tech support or replacement on the modem.

Comment: I got white page with Success hitting http://captive.apple.com/

I got redirected to https://shiningquietbrightyawn.neverssl.com/online/ hitting http://neverssl.com/

Comment: Based on your comment not all HTTP pages are failing so this is seemingly a change. Is http://tutor.com or other HTTP sites still failing? Have you tried to reproduce your issue while directly connecting to your ISP's equipment?

Comment: I am getting "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond." from any http endpoint.  Despite what was said above, http://captive.apple.com/ is redirecting to https.

Comment: captive.apple.com isn't redirecting to https here. Using firefox on OS X, developer tools in firefox indicates only http get requests. So SOMETHING is hijacking your web request: DNS, firewall, proxy, parental SW, etc. `tracert captive.apple.com` (well traceroute for linux/apple) here shows my router, unknown hop 2, then my ISP's eqp/hostname/router & I use a similar setup: netgear in access point mode connect to LAN port of main router

Comment: `tracert captive.apple.com

Tracing route to captive.g.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  modem.Home [192.168.0.1]
  3     6 ms     5 ms     5 ms  hlrn-dsl-gw05.hlrn.qwest.net [207.225.112.5]
  4     5 ms     6 ms    11 ms  63-225-124-33.hlrn.qwest.net [63.225.124.33]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6    12 ms     6 ms     6 ms  4.14.113.110
  7     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  usden5-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com [17.253.23.206]`